# Not able to config JDBC input

Tags: jdbc, logstash, logstash-configuration

below is my configuration -

```
input {
    jdbc {
           jdbc_driver_class => "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"   
           jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:derby://localhost:3306/test"
           jdbc_user => "root"
           jdbc_password => "password"
           statement => "select * from user"                    
         }
      }

filter {  
         #csv {
                #columns => ["cdatetime", "address", "district", "beat", "grid", "crimedescr", "ucr_ncic_code",
                #                                   "latitude","longitude"]          
                #separator => ","
             }
       #}

output { 
         elasticsearch { host => localhost protocol => http index => test user => pavan  password => password  } 
         stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
       }
```

When I run the config file, I get the following error -

```
The error reported is: 
  org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver not loaded
```

Can anyone please help me resolve it? My current Java version is -

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Any reference links about JDBC input configuration would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd wonder if the driver JAR is in the CLASSATH

Comment: How do I check that in Ubuntu?

Comment: Not an Ubuntu issue; it's a Java CLASSPATH issue. How do you package & deploy this app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262316/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-derby-jdbc-embeddeddriver)